# How to get currently Windows logged User Credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web app. It has it's login and own User interface. 
   I am trying to retrieve Windows logged users' credentials - like user name, email and password. On login in app, the logged in user's credentials are set as the User. So I need to retrieve windows logged in user's info before login process. I tried the following :

```
 // If domain is example.com, DomainName gives EXAMPLECOM. Plus can't access Password
 string evnName = Environment.UserDomainName + Environment.UserName;
```

In HomeController (after login) and Startup, I tried

```
// User is null   
string userName = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
```

I tried the above in a Service where login process is processed. Can't get from their too.

The main reason to retrieve this is to identify if the user has privileges for SMTP access or not, if so set SMTP.

Can anyone please help me know, how can I retrieve Windows Logged User's credentials somehow before Login process.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current Windows user credentials by using the  [System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netcore-2.1) static property.

You won't be able to get the password as that would be a major security hole.  You should be able to get everything else you want out of that, however.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, @Steve. I am still wondering, how to get the password and achieve the goal.

Comment: You cannot get the user's password.  That would be a major security hole in Windows and they would never allow it.

Comment: UseDefaultCredentials = true; did the trick. It uses the logged a/c and works. I will mark your answer as answer.